# WINFORM control Question (where is the slider?)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How do I go about getting a slider? I am unable to find the slider component inside of the toolbox.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you looking for the [TrackBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hat5zsd.aspx) control?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean the [Trackbar control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z8yazex.aspx)?